# Joomla cannot login to frontend

Tags: joomla

every user can't login to my joomla front-end, how should i trace it?
enabling debug mode won't give me good information to find what's wrong..
here's the debug mode output when i tried to log-in using correct password:

```
http://pastebin.ca/2303850
```

the joomla version is "Joomla! 1.5.18 Stable [ wojmamni ama wojnaiki ] TBA 04:00 GMT"

PHP version is "5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4"

mysql version is "5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.2"

previously it worked fine, but since 2013, it's not working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

upgrading to latest joomla (1.5.x) solves the problem..